# How can I take values From a table which is output of a function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This is a statement inside a stored procedure which gives a table output which contains date
dt:

```
SELECT [Dt] 
  FROM dbo.fnGetDatesforWeekDays(@dafromDate, @datoDate, @WKDAYS) AS DAT
```

How can I take those date values one by one?

Comment: "One by one"?  Can you provide more detail, an example for why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process them one by one you'll need to use a cursor and loop through the cursor:

```
DECLARE @Dt DATETIME

DECLARE date_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT [Dt]  
  FROM dbo.fnGetDatesforWeekDays(@dafromDate, @datoDate, @WKDAYS) AS DAT 

OPEN date_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM date_cursor INTO @Dt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
--do your processing here

FETCH NEXT FROM date_cursor INTO @Dt

END

CLOSE date_cursor

DEALLOCATE date_cursor
```

Just do whatever you want to do with each of those dates where the comment is and you're good to go.

Comment: I have created a temporary table and added one identity field

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (cursor, loop, ..)  .. but you shouldn't. Please post what are you trying to accomplish and most likely there is a better, set based solution.